# Retrieve a value from a HashSet of objects

Tags: java, hashset

Hi Guys just trying to brush up on my Java skills (forgotten so much). 
And for the life of me i cant remember how to print out a specific element from a HashSet of objects. So far ive created the objects and added them to the HashSet

```
    Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("Miss Marple", 63, "English");
    Teacher teacher2 = new Teacher("Mr White", 26, "Maths");
    Teacher teacher3 = new Teacher("Mrs Janet", 46, "Science");
    Teacher teacher4 = new Teacher("Mr Hancock", 35, "Art");
    Collection<Teacher> staff = new HashSet<Teacher>();
    staff.add(teacher1);
    staff.add(teacher2);
    staff.add(teacher3);
    staff.add(teacher4);
```

Now how do i go about retrieving and printing the name variable for each teacher object?

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: `HashSet` and its superclasses do not contain any `get()` method, and it is fundamentally unordered by definition. Are you sure you're using the right collection? HashSets are for very quick checks against existence/insurance of uniqueness.

Comment: HashSet might not be the best one to use, but its the one i remember using the most so it just came naturally to me to choose this one...

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Teacher teacher : staff) {
  ...
}
```

And if you need it in order of inserts use LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 0):

**Java 8** using stream

```
staff.stream().forEach(x->System.out.println(x.name));
```